# Highlight part of a math expression

Tags: discussion, mathjax

The following compiles under LaTeX

\(\left.x\right|_{x\gets\colorbox{yellow}{\(\mathsmaller{+2+h}\)}}\)

but how do I modify it to render under MathJaX?

Note: \colorbox is listed at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-commands

but not at http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#C

P.S. I hope this is the right place to ask. If not, where?

Comment: Some related posst: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference - Colors](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10116) and [On the use of \color in equations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/on-the-use-of-color-in-equations).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That does **not** compile under LaTeX. *This* compiles under LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color,relsize}
\begin{document}
\(\left.x\right|_{x\gets\colorbox{yellow}{\(\mathsmaller{+2+h}\)}}\)
\end{document}
```

The relevant point is that the commands `\colorbox` and `\mathsmaller` come from the packages `color` and `relsize`, respectively.

The `\colorbox` command is supported by MathJax because the `color` package has been implemented for MathJax, but you must use `\require{color}`, which is MathJax's method of loading a package.

The `relsize` package has not (currently) been implemented for MathJax, so that even writing `\require{relsize}` will not help, there is no way to use the `\mathsmaller` command.

The best you can do is something like

```
$$ \require{color} \left.x\right|_{x\gets\colorbox{yellow}{$+2+h$}} $$
```

which produces

$$ \require{color} \left.x\right|_{x\gets\colorbox{yellow}{$+2+h$}} $$

Comment: 1. Just to clarify: since I post very rarely, I do not really know how to make things show  so for the code to show as I had it (the same as yours), I added a couple of \ in front of the parentheses. 2. How do I acknowledge a perfect answer? 3. I need to find a tutorial on how to operate on stackexchange.

Comment: There is in fact no need for mathsmaller as your own post shows. So, the answer was not quire perfect. (But I am still very grateful.)

Comment: There is no need to `\require{color}`, you can use the
[BBox extension](http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tex.html#bbox)
 which is automatically loaded on math.SE.
You can do something like `\left.x\right|_{x\gets\bbox[yellow]{+2+h}}`
to get $$\left.x\right|_{x\gets\bbox[yellow]{+2+h}}$$

Comment: I wanted to experiement a bit with bbox before saying anything and it is indeed very nice. The only problem is that bbox is not a LaTeX command which makes it tedious when bringing in LaTeX for MathJaxing. Maybe somebody will make a bbox package for LaTeX, though.